# What does 1-1/2 mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In Pathfinder I've seen the phrase "adds 1-1/2 the creature's strength bonus on damage rolls"

Does that mean multiply by 1.5?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: I have asked about the origins of this notation on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1788470/44941), because frankly it’s awful and I want to know who to blame for this :P

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Yes.**

When the rules say "1-1/2" they mean 1.5 times. Remember to round *down*.

This is a holdover from 3.5, which also phrased it that way. Frankly I think "1.5" or "one and a half" would have been a better choice, precisely because it would avoid this kind of confusion, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: Thanks, it's a weird way of writing it on their part so I appreciate the clarification!

Comment: To be precise, it's a holdover from the *d20 SRD* which doesn't use typographical fractions (to maintain a lowest-common-denominator of text formatting) and favours numbers over words (for brevity/clarity); in D&D 3.5 they do use "one and a half times". Partly this is because an SRD isn't a teaching document, but rather a reference for those who have already learned the game, so it's written assuming the reader already knows this rule.

Comment: To clarify, "1-1/2" uses a system of notation that's only common in certain parts of the world. In this system of notation, the dash serves as a separator between the integer and fractional components of a number, meaning that "1-1/2" means "one and a half." I'm not sure how a separator that so closely resembles a minus sign ever caught on, but this is the world we live in.